# Meteor: file upload error

Tags: javascript, meteor, file-upload

I've been trying to use the meteor-uploads package (https://github.com/tomitrescak/meteor-uploads) to create a file upload system for my test webapp, the code for which can be found here:

http://meteorpad.com/pad/ckgN6GL4msQn4Ms5h/Jobs

I have made sure to install the necessary packages:

```
meteor add tomi:upload-server
meteor add tomi:upload-jquery
```

I couldn't find these on meteorpad so the link above probably won't work.

When I try this on my local machine, I get an error that says `UploadServer is not defined`, which then leads to file uploads giving a `503` error

I changed the code slightly from the example provided in the tutorial. When I use their code directly everything seems to work OK.

What/where is the error in my code that is causing the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this is because `process.env.PWD` returns `undefined` on Windows systems. This then leads to the uploader trying to upload to a directory without permissions. I've fixed this, for now, by manually specifying the upload directory path